# Getting and saving results from multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, imputation, r-mice

I have nine different data frames `df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8` and `df9`. I want to write a function that apply the following calculation using the `mice` package for each data frame individually:

```
imputed_Data <- mice(df, m=3, maxit = 3, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
```

by the end, I should get nine different `imputed_Data`.

what I did is:

```
for(i in 9) {
  imputed_Data <- mice(df[[i]], m=3, maxit = 3, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
  result[[i]] <- mice::complete(imputed_Data)
  }
```

Comment: I think you need `for(i in 1:9)` .  The way you've got it, the loop runs once, with `i = 9`.  But unless `df` is a list, `df[[i]]` won't evaluate to `df_9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `df`'s in a list

```
library(purrr)
dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8,  df9)
```

This will give it to you as a list of df's.

```
## NOT RUN ##
imputed_data <- 
  map(dfList, ~ mice(.x, m=3, maxit = 3, method = 'pmm', seed = 500))
```

If you want it as a single concatenated df

```
imputed_data <- 
  map_df(dfList, ~ mice(.x, m=3, maxit = 3, method = 'pmm', seed = 500))
```